# excel vba How to get a whole column range from a column number?

Tags: vba, excel

I can't think of an easier way to do this

Currently converting a column number to a letter with:

```
col_letter = Split(Cells(1, X).Address, "$")(1)
```

Then I'm defining an entire column range like so:

```
.Range(col_letter & ":" & col_letter)
```

Is there a simpler way?

**Background:**

I'm trying to use SUMIF in VBA

```
Dim col_letter as string
Dim my_total as double
Dim col_number as long

col_number = 15
col_letter = Split(Cells(1, X).Address, "$")(1)

my_total = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf( _ 
    .Range("A:A"), "Admix", .Range(col_letter & ":" & col_letter))
```

But I can't help thinking there must be some clever thing to define the range using the `col_number`

`.Range(col_letter).column` or something. I get confused between the `columns` and `column` properties, as I'm not sure how to use them.

Comment: Use number references instead of letters: `.columns(x)` should be enough (instead of `.Range(col_letter & ":" & col_letter)` ).

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks very much! I will get the hang of it, just never really used the property before!

Comment: You are going to hurt your performance by including all the cells in the Column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a number reference to a column instead a letter: `.Columns(x)` should be enough (instead of `.Range(col_letter & ":" & col_letter)`).